# Python selenium retrieve instagram followers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the list of followers from my account using a code like this using selenium (after authentication with username and pwd):

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/{0}/".format(account))

# Click the 'Follower(s)' link
r=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("follower").click()
print r
# Wait for the followers modal to load
xpath = "//div[@style='position: relative; z-index: 1;']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

# You'll need to figure out some scrolling magic here. Something that can
# scroll to the bottom of the followers modal, and know when its reached
# the bottom. This is pretty impractical for people with a lot of followers

# Finally, scrape the followers
xpath = "//div[@style='position: relative; z-index: 1;']//ul/li/div/div/div/div/a"
followers_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

the problem is the variable 'r' is 'None'. Is there a problem accessing your own followers?

Answer (score 1):

Click method returns nothing, so…r  is none